# Getting TreeMapEntry and HashMapNode ofTreeMap Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am using a TreeMap of String as Key, and value as another Map. My Map holds excel sheet data.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> excelData = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>>(
            String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

My excelData object size is 3. I have a TreeMapEntry called "Dates" with the size of 2. I want to retrieve this entry and merge it into a single enrty.

How can I do that?

Comment: if the data is this small why not use a 3 dimensional matrix ?

Comment: Because I fixing a bug in someone else code, so I am not allowed to change the types.

Comment: Provide the current contents of `excelData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(excelData.containsKey(key)) {
        // Get the value associated with a given key in a TreeMap
        Map name = excelData.get(key);
        System.out.println("excelData with key " + key + " : " + name);

     /* Now you can update this retrieved value. */
    }
```

Comment: Along with code please add some explanation as well